# How to use multiple blank identifiers in go?

Tags: go

I am trying to use more than one blank identifiers in a loop because I am not interested in the values but I am not able to use it.

Here's my code

```
x := [5]float64{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
for _, _ := range x {
    //Do some work
}
```

I am wondering how can one blank identifiers more than once in a statement?

The error I am getting is
`no new variables on left side of :=`

Comment: for range x { }

Comment: You can easily use multiple blank identifiers.. you just can't use `:=` when all the identifiers on the left are blank, because then `no new variables on left side of :=`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code uses short variable declaration, but no new variables are declared because the [blank identifier](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Blank_identifier) `_` does not represent a variable name.

Use the following code:

```
for _, _ = range x {
    //Do some work
}
```

Note use of [assignment](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments) instead of [short variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations).

Better yet, don't assign any variables as shown in comment by mh-cbon:

```
for range {
   //Do some work
}
```

The variable-free form was added in [Go 1.4](https://golang.org/doc/go1.4#forrange).

Answer (score 0):

When none of the variables are being used, you can ignore the blank identifiers.

```
x := [5]float64{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
for range x {
    //Do some work
}
```

As noted by @MonteDude , the `_` variable is already defined. This is why you get a `no new variables on left side of :=` error.